# C++ binary search function inconsistent

Tags: c++, object, vector, binary-search

For the most part, the below binary search function I have created works. However, sometimes for no apparent reason, the search will not find an entry when I know it exists. Also sometimes, the variable of `search` will have what the user inputted, but with the first letter missing. I have appended a `cin.clear()` along with the `cin.ignore()` to try to fix the this weird error. So far, after adding the `cin.clear()` I have not been able to recreate the issue.

View the program below:

```
void searchInventory(vector<Vehicle> &carList)
{
    cout << "You have chosen to search for a vehicle.\n\n";

        int  first = 0,                     // first, last, and  middle define the vector element subscripts
             last = (carList.size() - 1),
             middle,
             position = -1,                 // Needed to keep track of current position
             searchResult = 0;              // Used copy the data from position for use in displaying confirmation messages to the screen
        bool found = false;                 // Flag to tell program if search has been successful
        string search;                      // Used to hold user's input on what to search

        do
        {
            // Prompt to user so they can enter the make they are searching for
            cout << "Please enter the make of the vehicle you are searching for: ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.clear();
            getline(cin, search);

            cout << endl; 

            // Binary search algorithm begins...
            while (!found && first <= last)
            {
                middle = (first + last) / 2;
                if (carList[middle].getMake() == search)
                {
                    found = true;
                    position = middle;
                }

                else if (carList[middle].getMake() > search)
                    last = middle - 1;

                else
                    first = middle + 1;
            }

            searchResult = position;  // position is copied into searchResult

            if (searchResult == -1)   // if searchResult is -1, then the user specified word was not found
            {
                cout << "Sorry, there is no vehicles under the make of " << search << " in your inventory\n"
                     << "Please try again...\n\n";
            }

            else
            {
                // If the make was found, the information about the first vehicle with the specified model is given
                cout << search << "has been found...\n";

            }

        } while (searchResult == -1);
    }
}
```

Some background on this function: I am searching a vector objects for a member variable of a string data type that contains the make of a car.

So for example, if I search for "Ford" when "Ford" exists in the vector, the program most of the will say

> Ford has been found

But other times the program will say

> Sorry, there is no vehicles under the make of Ford in your inventory

And other times the program will say

> Sorry, there is no vehicles under the make of ord in your inventory

Notice the "ord" instead of "Ford" in the last one.

Does anyone have any clue why this binary search function can be so unpredictable?

Comment: It is difficult for us to look for an error that we cannot reproduce. How often does it occur, and with what data?

Comment: What exactly does `carList[middle].getMake() > search` expect to achieve? AFAIK you can't compare `std::strings` like that

Comment: I'm guessing the difference comes when you provide an even vs odd number of elements? And worth noting, you may consider changing `(first + last) / 2` to `first + (last - first)/2;` I would also strongly encourage you to use `last` as the first element you're *not* checking, similar to the "plus-one" element of iterator programming. It will make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why your code is not working you need to debug it or at least add some debug output. If you add something like

```
cout << "Now compare: " << carList[middle].getMake() << endl;
```

before `if (carList[middle].getMake() == search)` you'd see that sometimes (after first input) your program does not compare anything, since you have not re-initialized variables `found`, `first` and `last`.

You need to remove `cin.ignore();`, thats why you miss first character.

Corrected code:

```
void searchInventory(vector<Vehicle> &carList) {
    cout << "You have chosen to search for a vehicle.\n\n";

    string search;                      // Used to hold user's input on what to search
    int searchResult = 0;
    do {
        // Prompt to user so they can enter the make they are searching for
        cout << "Please enter the make of the vehicle you are searching for: ";
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, search);

        cout << endl;

        int first = 0,                      // first, last, and  middle define the vector element subscripts
            last = (carList.size() - 1),
            middle,
            position = -1;                  // Used copy the data from position for use in displaying confirmation messages to the screen
        bool found = false;                 // Flag to tell program if search has been successful

        // Binary search algorithm begins...
        while (!found && first <= last) {
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            if (carList[middle].getMake() == search) {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            } else if (carList[middle].getMake() > search) {
                last = middle - 1;
            } else {
                first = middle + 1;
            }
        }
        searchResult = position;  // position is copied into searchResult

        if (searchResult == -1) { // if searchResult is -1, then the user specified word was not found
            cout << "Sorry, there is no vehicles under the make of " << search << " in your inventory\n"
                 << "Please try again...\n\n";
        } else {
            // If the make was found, the information about the first vehicle with the specified model is given
            cout << search << " has been found...\n";
        }
    } while (searchResult == -1);
}
```

Also don't combine input with your algorithms. You better create more general function like `int vehicle_search(vector<Vehicle>& list, const string& search)` which returns index of vehicle in the vector or `-1` if it is not found. (It is only for example, you can also return pointer to the element, or iterator, and pass `Vehicle` insted of `string`). Then you will call it from somewhere in your program, check return value and output result.